# Asterisk insert a custom value in cdr table

Tags: asterisk, voip

I want to insert some custom value in CDR table, and i am using

Asterisk 11.10
MySQL 5.5.4

extensions.conf

```
[test]

exten => test,1,Answer()

exten => test,n,Set(CDR(my_var)=value)

exten => test,n,Playback(vm-from)

exten => test,n,SayDigits(${CALLERID(ani)})

exten => test,n,HangUp()
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need add that field my_var into table and restart asterisk

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would insert your custom values into the userfield. This can be done using the following:

```
exten => _X.,n,Set(CDR(userfield)=some_text)
```

As long as you don't have anything longer than 80 characters, you should be fine. I normally do something like this:

```
exten => _X.,n,Set(CDR(userfield)={'v1':'some_value'})
```

Which basically allows me to include multiple values in the userfield.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to insert the value of `my_var` to the cdr table from following line

```
exten => test,n,Set(CDR(my_var)=value)
```

, You will have to just add a column in the cdr table with name `my_var`. 
If that does not work, please cross check your cdr.conf file.

If your cdr.conf file is configured correctly, this will automatically update the value of set variables eg  `my_var` matched with columns in cdr table.